# Allure and screenshots

Tags: java, ui-automation, cucumber-jvm, allure

I am currently using cucumber json report for reporting from jenkins . 
This report is saving every screenshot from the tests in the memory and this often causes java heap memory error. 
I'd like to try allure but didn't find any info about it's behavior while creating the report.So I have a few questions:
1. Is allure report created during the tests execution or only after execution is finished all results are aggregated and written into the report?
2.Does the report embed the screenshots in the report or add them as links while the reports are stored somewhere else?
3.Are the screenshots saved in some folder or in the memory ?

Will appreciate any extra info about allure that can help me decide if we should switch to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Is allure report created during the tests execution or only after
>   execution is finished all results are aggregated and written into the
>   report?

The Allure report site is generated after test execution, when running `mvn site`. It makes use of the test execution information available in the surefire reports that were generated during execution of `mvn test`.

> Does the report embed the screenshots in the report or add them as
>   links while the reports are stored somewhere else?

Normally, screenshots are embedded in the report when the `@Attachment` annotation was used.

> Are the screenshots saved in some folder or in the memory ?

Screenshots are saved in the folder: `target/site/allure-maven-plugin/data`.